# Worksheet_Activate code fails to run in only 1 worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have a curious VBA problem. It has simple code to hide lines that aren't used. It has served me well, (I didn't actually make it) and all of the bugs fixed.

Now, however, it has stopped running the worksheet activate code in only one worksheet. The code for the other worksheets runs fine, and is nearly identical (list3 instead of list1 as a named range, and EntireColumn instead of EntireRow).

When I open Visual Basic and try to run the worksheet activate code manually, it gives me this error:

> Compile error: Object library invalid or contains references to object definitions that could not be found.

I don't know where to start to try to fix it, especially when the Google seems to yield no results, even with the new condescending logo.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In Range("list3") 'This changes to list1 to list4
        cell.EntireRow.Hidden = cell.Value2 = ""
    Next cell

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

**Edit:**

Two worksheets don't work now, I wonder if it has something to do with `"EntireRow.Hidden"`.

Comment: You will have to show the code to get any help. The SO community is pretty firm on that position. So just edit your question, and show us the code and the error that the line is on and someone should be able to help you out.

Comment: a) show the code and indicate what line is generating the error b) why aren't you using `Workbook_SheetActivate` and a [Select Case statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278665.aspx) on the Worksheet [.Name property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196974.aspx)?

Comment: @Constuntine Sorry, will post!

Comment: You might want to check Formulas ► Defined Names ► Name Manager for a valid `list3 ` with workbook scope.

Comment: @Jeeped A. I get the error as soon as I try to run it. (It highlights the first line, even when the sub isn't private.) B. I have no idea what that even means, I taught myself vba from here and a macro I found at work. I also didn't write the code. I assume the code was found using the dropdown in VBA with Worksheet on the left and Activate on the left. Edit: Yes, list1 to list4 have workbook scope

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code. Check the existence and validity of the Refers to: for `list3`.

Comment: If this is a cascading failure then you may be experiencing a corruption in the VBA project. Start by getting all code into a safe environment before proceeding.

Comment: Maybe http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsod/archive/2009/06/05/visual-basic-6-controls-stop-working-after-security-advisory-960715.aspx

Comment: You shouldn't write two statements on one line. Try to separate hidden (cell.entireRow.Hidden = True) and the assignment of "" to the cell value (cell.value = ""). Maybe that helps to avoid the error.

Comment: @Hubisan I think that actually works as an if statement... I will have to try it later... It means to hide the row if the cell is blank as I understand it

Comment: Try to narrow down the error by commenting out (' in front) the line with "cell.EntireRow..." and then check if there is still an error. If that line causes the error try it with an If...Then...Else statement. Else comment the for each loop out and try again etc. And google your error message.

Comment: @Hubisan it is an if statement... could be replaced with "if c.value = "" then cell.entireRow.hidden = true else cell.entireRow.hidden = false"

Answer (score 0):

Not activate is the failure, but deactivate. Before activate excel must deactivate active sheet, so if there is only one sheet... can't be deactivated!

You can try a trick, minimize then maximize by activate. Is going to have the same effect, if you put them on the same statement you will not even feel the break.

Comment: I have multiple sheets, and I get this when I switch between them. Deactivating isn't the problem.

Comment: First of all, for proper use you MUST place that code into the appropriate object module, the one containing the `list3` list. (e.g.Sheet1.Module). The reason for this is to give a reference for `worksheet_activate` to know which sheet to activate (since there can be only one `list3` ). Secondly, after you do the first step you could run the code within Visual Basic, it will reveal hidden rows, but because `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` the sheet won't activate, you must activate it manually.